# JavaFx for ARM (Raspberry Pi / BeagleBoard)

Tags: javafx, raspberry-pi

I am facing a lot of issues porting an application to ARM platform. I tried Java Embedded SE which works for simple application but fails for audioplayer.

I read this 
https://blogs.oracle.com/oslab/entry/javafx_application_on_the_ai

and

http://www.i-programmer.info/news/91-hardware/4167-javafx-runs-on-raspberry-pi.html

Is there any plan to develop / support JavaFX on ARM. From the blogs it seems like a test build is out there somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

Oracle released a [public developer preview of JavaFX for ARM which is tested for a Beagleboard](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html).

**Update**

There is now also a [public JDK8 early access release for JavaFX for Raspberry Pi](http://jdk8.java.net/fxarmpreview/javafx-arm-developer-preview.html).